# How to not add a new project to ALL configurations by default?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

There are many build configurations in the solution. When I create a new project in a solution, its build is assigned to ALL existing configurations.

I want it to be added only in Release and Debug configuration

Please tell me where to look :) I did not find suitable settings in the project templates.

Answer (score 0):

The default configurations are `Debug` and `Release`, and it’s for every(at least almost) projects. In solution’s Configuration Manager you can `Edit` or `New` a Configuration and manage for each project.

You can also try to use customized project templates, modify and set every configurations you want well and then export as an customized project template, and next time, just `New` this customized project template and add it to the solution. It will keep the settings(configurations) you set.([How to: Create project templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019))

More details are stored in project file(`.xxproj` file) which is related to MSBuild. You can also modify the [project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#project-file)(right-click the project > Unload Project > right-click it again > Edit Project File).